# Sign of the derivative of $(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x+1}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

How can I show that the derivative of $f(x)=(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x+1}$ is negative for $x>0$?

With logarithmic differentiation, I get

$$f'(x)=f(x)\left(\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)-\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

But I can't seem to establish that the second term is unambiguously negative. I've tried to use the fact that $\ln(1+1/x)<1+1/x$ but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Use the fact that $\log (1 + w) < w$ for all $w>0$.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Is there a quick proof for this fact?

Comment: For $w = 0$, $\log(1 + w) = w$. For $w > 0$, the derivative of $\log(1+w) < 1$, and it is continuous. With that and the mean value theorem, you can show there cannot be a value $w > 0$ such that $\log(1 + w) \geq w$.

Comment: Thanks @robby the Belgian
I tried the method you suggested to show $ln x< x$ but $1/x <1$ only for x>1 even though ln x < x for all x>0. Could you help with this?

Comment: Don't forget to use $\log(1 + x)$, not $\log(x)$.