# How to show that $\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{x+1}$ is decreasing for $x\gt0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I had asked a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237947/let-fx-left1-dfrac1x-rightx-and-gx-left1-dfrac1x-rightx1-th), that sought to comment about the increasing/decreasing nature of $f(x)=\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{x}$ and $g(x)=\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{x+1}$. While I got a reply for the former, not for the latter.

$\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{x+1}=\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{x}\left(1+\frac1x\right)=$increasing function $\times$ decreasing function.

Also, $g'(x)=f'(x)\left(1+\frac1x\right)+f(x)\cdot-\frac1{x^2}=(+ve)\times(+ve)+(+ve)\times(-ve)$

Not able to conclude anything. Can you help? Thanks.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2306703/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3903311/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/306178/42969 – all found quickly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cleft(1%2B%5Cfrac1x%5Cright)%5E%7Bx%2B1%7D%24%2C%20AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @aarbee yeah, check the links Martin R has provided. These are hints to how you can work it out.

Comment: Thankyou. I am looking at the link now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $(1+1/a)^{a+1}<(1+1/b)^{b+1}$ if $a>b>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2306703/prove-that-11-aa111-bb1-if-ab0)